# sharepoint resize verticle scroll

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery

I am going to add a custom div in b/w ribbon and workspace div. I find the scrolling bug

**HTML**

```
<!-- ribbon -->
<div class="s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle" id="s4-ribbonrow" style="height: 44px;">
</div>
<!-- ribbon end -->

<!-- ribbon -->
<div id="s4-header">
  custom header
</div>
<!-- ribbon -->

<!-- ribbon -->
<div id="s4-workspace" style="height: 1045px; width: 1600px;">
</div>
<!-- ribbon -->
```

this is the structure of masterpage.

and I m using the following jquery script.

```
function FixWorkspace() {
  // if you are using a header that is affixed to the top (i.e. SharePoint Ribbon) put the ID or class here to change the workspace height accordingly.
  var header = '#s4-header';
  var width = $(window).width();
  var height;
  if ($(header).length) {
    height = $(window).height() - ($(header).height()+90);
  } else {
    height = $(window).height();
  }
  $('#s4-workspace').width(width).height(height);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   FixWorkspace();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
   FixWorkspace();
});
```

on page load, this script works and set the height value but suddenly after some seconds it revert to default height value (i.e 1045px ).
any help in this regards.

Comment: I wouldn't put anything between these to DIVs. What if you place your div inside #s4-workspace?

Comment: I can, but the issue is... when you scroll down, the custom div will hide behid the riboon.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

1. Remove the inline height and move to external css
2. Now apply your JQuery Script.

Comment: any idea, how to remove the inline height :).

Comment: If the inline script is added dynamically, you have to run your script after the default script is loaded.

Comment: yes, I already tried this, my jquery script in just before </body> tag

Comment: 1) You can try using differ if your are using script src or 2) use sharepoint scriptlink and aftercss property

Comment: you mean <script src="" >

Comment: I am using the inline script, its more stronger than src.
I also tried before the 'src'.but still not work.

Comment: Can you please post your complete script reference.   Ex: <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/jquery.js" defer="defer" ></script>